# How to get a value from local storage with asyncStorage and return it

Tags: javascript, react-native, asynchronous, asyncstorage

I want to create a method that returns an auth header from a token stored in the local storage so it can be called from many ajax, like this:

```
const fetchUserInfo = (username) => {
  const requestString = apiBaseURL + 'access/user_info/'
  const form = {username: username}

  return axios.post(requestString, form, getAuthHeader())
    .then((Response) => {
      return {
        userInfo: Response.data,
        message: null
      }
    })
    .catch((Error) => {
      return getErrorMessage();
    });
}
```

In this case, `getAuthHeader()` is a method that must return a proper authorization header from a token stored in the local storage, so it must use `asyncStorage` in order to retrieve such token.

This is the code for `getAuthHeader`:

```
export const getAuthHeader = async () => {
  return await AsyncStorage.getItem('token')
    .then ((token) => {
      return {
        headers: {'Authorization' : 'Token ' + token}
      }
    })
    .catch ((error) => null)
}
```

The problem is that `getAuthHeader()` is not returning a header but some other object. I believe I am messing up with the asynchronous nature of `asyncStorage`, but I can't figure out how to get the value I need.

Comment: `.catch ((error) => null)`. Code like that will take you down a rabbit hole that you may never return from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are using `async/await` and `.then` (native) together. `async/await` already handles the `.then` syntax for you without you having to do it. So you do not need both together it's 1 or the other. Both examples below.

Async/Await:

```
export const getAuthHeader = async () => {
  try {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token')
    if (!token) { return null }
    return {
        headers: {'Authorization' : 'Token ' + token}
      }
  } catch(error) { return null }

}
```

Native

```
export const getAuthHeader = () => {
  return AsyncStorage.getItem('token')
    .then((token) => {
      if (!token) { return null }
      return {
        headers: {'Authorization' : 'Token ' + token}
      }
    })
    .catch ((error) => null)
}
```

also you need to await `getAuthHeader` in your first method else it will never resolve that value:

```
const fetchUserInfo = async (username) => {
  const requestString = apiBaseURL + 'access/user_info/'
  const form = {username: username}
   
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(requestString, form, await getAuthHeader())
    return {
        userInfo: response.data,
        message: null
    }
  } catch(error) {
    return getErrorMessage();
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I can see that `AsyncStorage`  retrieves the proper value but, in the calling method, `getAuthHeader` is not receiving the header but another object. I suspect it is a promise, but I don't know how to find it out and, if so, how to solve it.

Comment: The problem is than, then, `fetchUserInfo()` would become a promise and the method calling it would need to become `async` too, and that is not possible.

Comment: to do what you want it has to become a promise. Unless you dont use an async storage.

Comment: what can I use instead if I need a persistent local storage?

Comment: yes if you want this all to not be async code you need to use something sync like local storage.

Comment: isn't it deprecated?

Comment: no https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage, supported on all browsers and used in most websites.

Comment: why can your method before not turn `async`? should be as easy as just marking it async and then awaiting this method and then so on for other things which call it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226188/discussion-between-hulu-vica-and-josh-stevens).